# Cannot read property state

Tags: vuejs2, jestjs, mocking, state, action

I try to test this action:

```
const getGameList = function(context) {
  if(context.state.user.id){
    let request_body = {
        user_id : context.state.user.id
    }
    axios.post(`api/game_list_of_user`,request_body).then(response => {
      context.commit('UpdateGameList',response.data);
    }).catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
};
```

My action is to get the list of game for a specific user.
This action has:

- as input my user id .
- as output my game of list.

My test:

```
import actions from '@/store/actions'
import state from '@/store/state'
import store from '@/store'
import axios from 'axios'

jest.mock('axios');

describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', () => {
    
    const state = { user: {id: 1} };
    const mockFunction = jest.fn();
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response);

    actions.getGameList({ mockFunction },{ state });

    //expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    //expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('UpdateGameList',response.data);

  });

  test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Error';
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
    );
  });

});
```

1. I declare my state (with my user id).
2. I declare my expected response
   from my request (the game list = response.data).
3. I use jest.fn() to mock the function. (Should I do that ?)

I got this error:
[image]

I want to check:

- My request has been called
- The response of my request matches with my expected response
- My mutation is then called

How can I solve that error?

Edit1: my test

```
jest.mock('axios');

describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', () => {
    
    const context = {
      state : { 
        user: {
          id: 1
        } 
      }
    };
    const mockFunction = jest.fn();
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response);

    actions.getGameList({ mockFunction, context });

    expect({ mockFunction, context }).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockFunction).toHaveBeenCalledWith('UpdateGameList',response.data);

  });

  test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Error';
    axios.get.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
    );
  });
});
```

Comment: The first argument to getGameList, the only one it expects, is supposed to be the context. You seem to be passing that as the *second* argument in the test.

Comment: So I supposed to have "context" as input and not state in my test? I tried to declare in my test: const context = { state: { user: { id:1 } } }; but I have the same error...

Comment: Are you still passing it as the *second* argument? What is `getGameList` supposed to be doing with `{ mockFunction }`?

Comment: getGameList is supposed to give me an array of object (id and name as attribute). I have only user_id of my store as parameter. 
I don't understand: Are you still passing it as the second argument?
I have only 1 parameter.

Comment: You only *defined* one parameter, but you're passing two arguments: `actions.getGameList({ mockFunction },{ state })`

Comment: ok so I passed only 1 argument in my function (and redefined my context) but still the same error
I changed my code like that:
const context = {
      state : { 
        user: {
          id: 1
        } 
      }
    };
actions.getGameList({ mockFunction, context });

Comment: [Edit] the question. Also just *think about what you're doing* - `getGameList` doesn't expect its parameter to have `context` or `mockFunction` props. It expects it to *be* a context, with a `state` prop, and will do nothing at all with the `mockFunction`.

Comment: I think I don't get it what is mockFunction when we do jest.fn() ...

Comment: Then see e.g. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions

Comment: ok so if I understand what I read, the mock function replaces the real function with something virtual and the real function is not really called?  Am I right? 
If I am, I should mock my API call and then check if my mutation is called after the resolve of my API call ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my solution:

```
import actions from '@/store/actions'
import mutations from '@/store/mutations'
import state from '@/store/state'
import store from '@/store'
import axios from 'axios'

let url = ''
let body = {}

jest.mock("axios", () => ({
  post: jest.fn((_url, _body) => { 
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      url = _url
      body = _body
      resolve(true)
    })
  })
}))

//https://medium.com/techfides/a-beginner-friendly-guide-to-unit-testing-the-vue-js-application-28fc049d0c78
//https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest
//https://lmiller1990.github.io/vue-testing-handbook/vuex-actions.html#testing-actions
describe('getGameList', () => {
  test('Success: should return the game list of the user and update gameList in the store', async () => {
    const context= {
      state: {
        user: {
          id:1
        }
      },
      commit: jest.fn()
    }
    const response = {
      data: [ 
        { id:1, name:"game_name1" },
        { id:2, name:"game_name2" }
      ]
    };

    axios.post.mockResolvedValue(response) //OR axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(response));
    await actions.getGameList(context)
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith("api/game_list_of_user",{"user_id":1});
    expect(axios.post).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    expect(context.commit).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UpdateGameList", response.data)

  });

  test('Error: an error occurred', () => {
    const errorMessage = 'Error';
    axios.post.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.reject(new Error(errorMessage))
    );
  });

});
```